# Convertir de hexadecimal​ a decimal en Java

Tags: java, android

Quiero convertir de hexadecimal a decimal. Estoy desarrollando en Android Studio, y
aquí está el fragmento del método.

```
public void calcularDec() {

    EditText numero1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumero1);
    int n = Integer.parseInt(numero1.getText().toString().trim(),16);


    Toast.makeText(this, "El resultado es: " + n, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: ¿Y qué problema te está dando? ¿Te muestra algún error o simplemente no te da el resultado esperado? Es decir, ¿cuál es la pregunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No especificas cual es el hexadecimal de entrada, por lo que te dejo unos ejemplos explicados:
Int es capaz de almacenar 2147483657 (0x7fffffff) por lo que el valor hexadecial no podra sobrepasar ese valor, para solventar eso puedes usar Long:

```
EditText numero1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumero1);
long n = Long.parseLong(numero1.getText().toString(), 16);
Toast.makeText(this, "El resultado es: " + n, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Si tu valor de entrada es menor a lo anteriormente dicho, es entonces conveniente usar Int.

```
EditText numero1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumero1);
int n = Integer.parseInt(numero1.getText().toString(), 16);
Toast.makeText(this, "El resultado es: " + n, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Otra manera podria ser con este esquema

```
Integer.decode("0x4d2") //devolverá 1234
```